# Regular expression for matching a query string

Tags: regex

I have a log file which have logs very similar to Apache logs

Here is a sample log line

```
41.13.0.155 - - [03/May/2012:00:00:08 -0700] "GET /gameState?type=udid&udid=A100001837E58D4&game=TapFish HTTP/1.1" 200 38812 - "Dalvik/1.4.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; GT-B5510 Build/GINGERBREAD)"
```

I am able to separate this string from log line `"GET /gameState?type=udid&udid=A100001837E58D4&game=TapFish HTTP/1.1"`

I want to iterate all the lines to grab all the log line which fulfil following condition
Log line should have `"GET /gameState?type=[[anything]]"` but [[anything]] should not be `'neighbor'`

Please suggest some regular expression which can match the string on above conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood all of your constraints, but this should work:

```
.+GET /gameState(?!.*type=neighbor\b).*
```

You're basically not matching if it spots `type=neighbor` anywhere after `gameState`, and only if `neighbor` is at word boundary (`type=neighborhood` is ok).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match a line that doesn't include a substring:

```
.+GET /gameState\?type=(?!neighbor).+
```

Comment: Depending on the match he's trying to make, it could be better to use `.+GET /gameState\?type=(?!neighbor\b).+`; the `\b` ensues the match is at **word boundary**, which could be useful if something like _neighborhood_ is a good match. Nonetheless, the answer is probably just right by itself ;)

Comment: It does works fine where we have a parameter type, But i want to match also those urls which dont have a type= parameter. like the following URL
"GET /gameState"

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead to exclude the neighbor:

```
for line in logfile:
    match = re.search("GET /gameState?type=(?!neighbor)", line")
```

Comment: This doesn't match what comes after `type=`. (Lookaheads don't participate in the match.)

Comment: its not matching whatever comes after type=